# what is the best way to add a variable defining different stacks in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We have a terraform code to creating a stack, example of the code is as follows:

```
//Attach Iam Policy with Iam role
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AProcessLambdaPolicyAttachment_avl" {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.AProcessLambdaRole_avl.name}"
    policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.EventProcessorLambdaPolicy_avl.arn}"
}
```

As one can see we use the suffix avl to identify the resources from the stack resulted from applying this terraform.  What to do for several stacks? Can I specify a variable for stack identification, for example

```
variable "stack" {
    type = string
    default = "mal1"
}
```

Then I would like to use this variable instead of suffix.  Is it possible?  What will be the syntax? What is the way to overwrite the default value?